# Java сервис AppLock - Как узнать пакет запускаемый пользователем (в реальном времени)?

Tags: java, android

Как узнать пакет запускаемый пользователем (в реальном времени)?

Comment: пакет *приложения*, запускаемого пользователем?

Comment: Да. Пробую через .getRunningAppProcesses(), но в реальном времени мониторить получится только c TimerTask(). Вот и думаю можно ли как то это сделать с помощью BroadcastReceiver()

Comment: мне кажется, что такой возможности нет. Я бы лично не хотел, чтобы любая программа смогла узнать, что у меня запускается. Кроме того, насколько я помню, с определенной версии андроида `getRunningAppProcesses()` тоже будет возвращать только процесс ланчера и свой собственный

Comment: Вот `getRunningTasks()` уже имеет статус Deprecated, но `getRunningAppProcesses()`, пока никто не собирается отменять ;) Если не будет такой возможности, то как же будет тяжко антивирусникам...